# MongoDB connection issues from PHP driver

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I've been getting random application transaction traces in my NewRelic account that indicate that php is sometimes having a hard time connecting to my MongoDB replica set.

The transaction trace indicates that MongoConnection::getConnection sometimes takes 1-6 seconds.  However the transaction I'm monitoring takes on average about 25ms.

This is my connection class:

```
class MongoConnection {
    static $db = NULL;

    static function getConnection() {
        if (self::$db === null) {
            try {
                $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://server1:27017,server2:27017/?replicaSet=replicaset");
            } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
                die('Failed to connect to MongoDB '.$e->getMessage());
            }
           self::$db = $m->database;
        } 
        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

I'm running MongoDB v2.4 and PHP driver v1.3.4.

I have no idea why this would be happening nor do I know exactly what to look for to diagnose the issue. If someone could tell me what's going on or point me in the direction of where I should be looking for the issue please let me know. Happy to supply additional information.  Thanks.

Comment: Poke around http://server1:27018 and see if there's any unusual things

Comment: Bandwidth transmitted/received and packets per second seem to go up 50% - 100% around the time of the trace - but its not consistent with every trace and not always on server1.  Sometimes it's on server2 and even server3 which is the arbiter.

Comment: You can utilize the [MongoLog](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongolog.php) class to debug internal driver behavior. That may reveal the source of the connection delays.